# Skinning Java desktop applications?

Tags: java, swing, customization, look-and-feel, skin

Does anybody know a way to "skin" Java desktop applications. (Like Winamp skins, or skins for MirandaIM)?
I don't want to create my own look and feel.

Comment: Sry, I'm talking about desktop apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways this can be done, but I don't know anyone that is really simple. Have a look at [Nimbus: The New Face of Swing](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-6096.pdf), it contains a few examples. You can often override the look of components or just change the colors.

Some links:

- [Nimbus Colors](http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html)
- [Skinning a Slider with Nimbus](http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/skinning-a-slider-with-nimbus/)
- [Nimbus UIManager UIDefaults](http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/nimbus-uimanager-uidefaults/)

And you can always change to another LaF, in example [Substance](https://substance.dev.java.net/see.html).

Comment: Nimbus looks very good. Do you know a way to change the shape of a window (e.g rounded corners or an elliptic shaped window)?

Comment: Yes, have a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Answer (score 4):

We've successfully used the [NimROD Look and Feel](http://nilogonzalez.es/nimrodlf/index-en.html) to 'skin' the Swing look & feel.  It works well, has several 'themes' already written for it, and can be added in a few lines of code.

Comment: Nimrod is awesome I have used that many times in conjunction with Miglayout, all other layouts pale in comparison

Answer (score 1):

For a project that's still actively maintained in 2022 and allows skinning of Swing applications try [FlatLaf](https://github.com/JFormDesigner/FlatLaf)

> FlatLaf is a modern open-source cross-platform Look and Feel for Java
> Swing desktop applications.
>
> It looks almost flat (no shadows or gradients), clean, simple and
> elegant. FlatLaf comes with Light, Dark, IntelliJ and Darcula themes,
> scales on HiDPI displays and runs on Java 8 or newer.
>
> The look is heavily inspired by Darcula and IntelliJ themes from
> IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2+ and uses almost the same colors and icons.

Answer (score 0):

Swing has built-in dynamic look and feel support. If you are talking about desktop apps, you might want to start with [Lesson: Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/).

Edit: If you are talking about a webapp, then absolutely use different `.css` to acheive a skinnable interface.  [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is a great example/tutorial on how the same page can look entirely different with a different `.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another modern look and feel active maintained in 2022 is https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing

It include also a way to develop a custom theme in an external jar, like this one https://github.com/material-ui-swing/DarkStackOverflowTheme